# How to make client trust self signed certificate Java SSL

Tags: java, ssl, networking, cryptography, keystore

I created a self signed certificate using java's keytool

> keytool -genkeypair -alias my_home -keystore herong.jks

On the client i have.

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "herong.jks");
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "HerongJKS");
```

On the server I have

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "herong.jks");
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "HerongJKS");

String ksName = "herong.jks";
        char ksPass[] = "HerongJKS".toCharArray();
        char ctPass[] = "My1stKey".toCharArray();
        try {
            KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
            ks.load(server.class.getResourceAsStream(ksName), ksPass);
            KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
            kmf.init(ks, ctPass);
            SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
            sc.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), null, null);
            //listen for connections
            }
```

I have the jks file in both the server and client package however the client can't get past the handshake when trying to connect to the server over two computers.

Comment: What is the exception you are getting?